# Undefined property in filter method

Tags: angular

I have an issue with the following method. I am the following error `Cannot read property 'selectedMAP' of undefined`.

```
const selectedPlan = {"name": "basic", "amount": 1000}
  let dependantsCost = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.planCosts[0].selectedMAP.length; i++) {
   for (let j = 0; j < this.planCosts[0].selectedMAP[i].options.length; j++) {
    if (selection.medicalAid.numberOfAdultDependants > 0) {
       const costForAdultDependant = this.planCosts.filter(x => x.selectedMAP[i].options[j].optionName.toLowerCase() == selectedPlan.name.toLowerCase())[0].selectedMAP[i].options[j].adultDependantAmount;
       const numberOfAdultDependants = selection.medicalAid.numberOfAdultDependants;
       dependantsCost += numberOfAdultDependants * costForAdultDependant;
    } 
  }
}
```

This is the data set that I am filtering on

```
[
  {
    "corporateId": "a682fafc-372a-4bbf-9b42-fe8b35cc437f",
    "selectedMAP": [
      {
        "mapId": 32,
        "mapName": "one",
        "active": true,
        "options": [
          {
            "optionId": 49,
            "optionName": "basic",
            "memberAmount": 1000,
            "adultDependantAmount": 500,
            "childDependantAmount": 500,
            "active": true
          },
          {
            "optionId": 50,
            "optionName": "advanced",
            "memberAmount": 2000,
            "adultDependantAmount": 1000,
            "childDependantAmount": 2000,
            "active": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "mapId": 33,
        "mapName": "two",
        "active": true,
        "options": [
          {
            "optionId": 51,
            "optionName": "lite",
            "memberAmount": 1000,
            "adultDependantAmount": 500,
            "childDependantAmount": 500,
            "active": true
          },
          {
            "optionId": 52,
            "optionName": "heavy",
            "memberAmount": 2000,
            "adultDependantAmount": 500,
            "childDependantAmount": 500,
            "active": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this.planCosts[0] is equal to this

```
{
  "corporateId": "a682fafc-372a-4bbf-9b42-fe8b35cc437f",
  "selectedMAP": [
    {
      "mapId": 32,
      "mapName": "one",
      "active": true,
      "options": [
        {
          "optionId": 49,
          "optionName": "basic",
          "memberAmount": 1000,
          "adultDependantAmount": 500,
          "childDependantAmount": 500,
          "active": true
        },
        {
          "optionId": 50,
          "optionName": "advanced",
          "memberAmount": 2000,
          "adultDependantAmount": 1000,
          "childDependantAmount": 2000,
          "active": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "mapId": 33,
      "mapName": "two",
      "active": true,
      "options": [
        {
          "optionId": 51,
          "optionName": "lite",
          "memberAmount": 1000,
          "adultDependantAmount": 500,
          "childDependantAmount": 500,
          "active": true
        },
        {
          "optionId": 52,
          "optionName": "heavy",
          "memberAmount": 2000,
          "adultDependantAmount": 500,
          "childDependantAmount": 500,
          "active": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea why this could be throwing me an error?

Comment: Have you assigned the this json to planCosts properly?

Comment: When you call this method this.planCosts[0] is undefined, how do you get it?

Comment: @FedMice I have updated the question to show what this.planCosts[0] gives. I get this from an endpoint call

Comment: @Indrajeet I have updated the question to show what  this.planCosts[0] gives

Comment: Problem lies in filter line, you should always check the length after applying filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error gives in this part 
`this.planCosts.filter(...)[0].selectedMAP[i]`,
when the length of the filtered output becomes zero. You can use it like this to avoid the error.

```
const lenOfFiltered = this.planCosts.filter(...).length;
if (lenOfFiltered ) {
    this.planCosts.filter(...)[0].selectedMAP[i].options[j].adultDependantAmount;
}
```

Thank you!